# Make Buildings rise from the ground

Tags: animation

I want to know how one can achieve a video like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJNJZX2sLlU - how can you make the buildings rise from the ground, put the map on the ground and create a rotation around the block like at the end of the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just put the building below the scene (ground) and animate them on the z-axis to go up. if you want the camera to go around the block smoothly change the origin of the camera. You can do this by getting an object out of view and the camera to make the block in the centre of rotation

[image]

shift select them both.

[image]

Then just rotate them on the z-axis by pressing "r" then "z". this will make them rotate around the block.

[image]

and now all you need to do is animate it!